# how to parsing the data ...and populate the data in tableview

Tags: ios

```
         {
                "COMPETITION_CODE":"UCC0000003",
                "MATCH_CODE":"DMSC1160026829B543400022",
                "MATCH_DATE":"1/18/2016 12:00:00 AM",
                "A_TEAMNAME":"UTTAR PRADESH",
                "B_TEAMNAME":"DELHI",
                "A_TEAMSHORTNAME":"UPCA",
                "B_TEAMSHORTNAME":"DHL",
                "BATTING_TEAMNAME":"UTTAR PRADESH",
                "MATCH_TYPE":"MSC116",
                "HOME_TEAM":"UTTAR PRADESH",
                "FIRSTINNINGS_SHORTNAME":"DHL",
                "FIRSTINNINGS_SCORE":"158/6",
                "FIRSTINNINGS_TOTAL":"158",
                "FIRST_INNINGSWICKET":"6",
                "FIRST_INNINGSOVERS":"20.0",
                "SECOND_INNINGSSHORTNAME":"UPCA",
                "SECOND_INNINGSSCORE":"159/7",
                "SECOND_INNINGSTOTAL":"159",
                "SECOND_INNINGSWICKET":"7",
                "SECOND_INNINGSOVERS":null,
                "THIRD_INNINGSSHORTNAME":"",
                "THIRD_INNINGSSCORE":"0/0",
                "THIRD_INNINGSTOTAL":"0",
                "THIRD_INNINGSWICKET":"0",
                "THIRD_INNINGSOVERS":"",
                "FOURTH_INNINGSSHORTNAME":"",
                "FOURTH_INNINGSSCORE":"0/0",
                "FOURTH_INNINGSTOTAL":"0",
                "FOURTH_INNINGSWICKET":"0",
                "FOURTH_INNINGSOVERS":"",
                "FIRST_INNINGSLOGO":null,
                "SECOND_INNINGSLOGO":null,
                "RUN_RATE":"8.1",
                "REQUIREDRUN_RATE":"0.0",
                "MATCH_RESULT":"Won by 3 Wickets",
                "Player_TeamList":[
                   {
                       "PLAYER_NAME":"PRAVEEN KUMAR",
                       "PLAYER_ROLE":"Bowler",
                       "TEAM_NAME":"UTTAR PRADESH",
                       "TEAM_CODE":"TEA0000001",
                       "PLAYER_ORDER":"1"
                   },
                   {
                       "PLAYER_NAME":"AKSHDEEP NATH",
                       "PLAYER_ROLE":"Batsman",
                       "TEAM_NAME":"UTTAR PRADESH",
                       "TEAM_CODE":"TEA0000001",
                       "PLAYER_ORDER":"1"
                   },
                   {
                       "PLAYER_NAME":"AMIT MISHRA",
                       "PLAYER_ROLE":"Bowler",
                       "TEAM_NAME":"UTTAR PRADESH",
                       "TEAM_CODE":"TEA0000001",
                       "PLAYER_ORDER":"1"
                   },
                   {
                       "PLAYER_NAME":"PIYUSH CHAWLA",
                       "PLAYER_ROLE":"All Rounder",
                       "TEAM_NAME":"UTTAR PRADESH",
                       "TEAM_CODE":"TEA0000001",
                       "PLAYER_ORDER":"1"
                   },
                   {
                       "PLAYER_NAME":"ANKIT RAJPOOT",
                       "PLAYER_ROLE":"Bowler",
                       "TEAM_NAME":"UTTAR PRADESH",
                       "TEAM_CODE":"TEA0000001",
                       "PLAYER_ORDER":"1"
                   }]
                }
```

i tried for the parsing  got response values in serviceResponse but need to populate the array and dictionary values in tableview index path

any one pls help me to solve this issues

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSDictionary *serviceResponse=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post the actual response you are getting, the response you have provide seem have only one object, Is it like you have to display the data in one cell or what, explain. Edit sorry i have not view the Question properly, you have already provided the full response.

Comment: So you have to display "PLAYER_NAME":"PIYUSH CHAWLA",
                       "PLAYER_ROLE":"All Rounder",
                       "TEAM_NAME":"UTTAR PRADESH",
                       "TEAM_CODE":"TEA0000001",
                       "PLAYER_ORDER":"1"  on cell?

Comment: s Bharat Modi I have to pass all values on cell not only the array values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, from the response you have provided, it seems that you have to display below attributes on tableView cell,

```
{
   "PLAYER_NAME":"PRAVEEN KUMAR",
   "PLAYER_ROLE":"Bowler",
   "TEAM_NAME":"UTTAR PRADESH",
   "TEAM_CODE":"TEA0000001",
   "PLAYER_ORDER":"1"
}
```

You should parse the data as

```
NSDictionary *serviceResponse=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSArray *arrayOfPlayer_TeamList = serviceResponse[@"Player_TeamList"];
```

And once you parse the response, reload the tableView on main thread.

**Edit/Update:**

If you have to use the whole response, then just parse the response in serviceResponse dictionary as you have parsed already, make the dictionary global and inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

1. When you have to display match date,

   ```
   NSString *matchDate = serviceResponse[@"MATCH_DATE"];
   ```
2. And when you have to display 'PLAYER_NAME' which would be different for each cell,

   ```
   NSString *playerName = serviceResponse[@"Player_TeamList"][indexPath.row][@"PLAYER_NAME"];
   ```

Hope this would help you.

**Edit2/Update2:**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [_dictTeamData[@"Player_TeamList"] count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    //Team Name & Batting Team Name are outside Player_TeamList

    //Team Name
    UILabel *teamName = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:10];
    teamName.text = _dictTeamData[@"A_TEAMNAME"];

    //Batting Team Name
    UILabel *battingTeamName = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:20];
    battingTeamName.text = _dictTeamData[@"BATTING_TEAMNAME"];


    //Player Name & Player Role inside Player_TeamList
    //Player Name
    UILabel *playerName = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:30];
    playerName.text = _dictTeamData[@"Player_TeamList"][indexPath.row][@"PLAYER_NAME"];

    //Player Role
    UILabel *playerRole = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:40];
    playerRole.text = _dictTeamData[@"Player_TeamList"][indexPath.row][@"PLAYER_ROLE"];
    return cell;
}
```

And the result is:

[image]